# single forgot password link in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i have two devise user model

- Company
- Employee

i want to send forgot password link from Company's inbuilt passwords_controller for both users because i have single sign in page for both.

so how can i do that.

i tried like this in  passwords_controller.rb of company model :-

```
def create
  @employee = Employee.new
  @company = Company.new
  domain=request.subdomain
  if @company.email_exist?(domain,params[:company][:email])
    super
  elsif @employee.email_exist?(domain, params[:company][:email])
    params[:employee] = {:email => params[:company][:email]}
    params.delete :company
    params[:controller]='employees/passwords'
    redirect_to :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :params => params, :method => :POST
  end
end
```

simply it check email in company tables if yeas then it call super method

otherwise check in employee table if yes then it change the params from company to employee and pass to employees passwords_controller

but it not work.

help me..

thanks in advance.!!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it not work"?

Comment: @Pierre-Jean : in short i have two devise user models **company** and **employee** and i use single sign in page for both users. means i used companies default devise controller for sign in so when i click on forgot password it considers only company so how can i send forgot password link to employee when i enters employee email.